# Can not click on a button; - "element is not interactable"

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

I have a script where I'm trying to push a button on an ecommerce site but when I run a script I get `"Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable "` .

When I put xpath into the chropath, element is located so I guess path  `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//form/fieldset[2]/button")).click();` is right. Please see attached screenshots and be gentle I'm new to programming and this site :/

[image: website]

[image: code]

Comment: You should use a wait for your webdriver to do this you can do an explicit wait with sleep or use a special until available command. Also I would check to be sure you have the right element

Comment: You should update the question, add url and your code, others can use this to help you out. Image is not a proper way to show code.

Comment: @Alex Don't post images. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see, there's an Accept cookies button, if you want to click on that, you can use the below code :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))).click();
```

and then click on `Sleeve length` like this  :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//form/fieldset[2]/button"))).click();
```

Note that you should open browser in full screen before interacting any web element.

```
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("Your URL");
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The issue was that the window wasn't maximized.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a JavascriptExecutor to trigger the click:

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", yourWebElement);
```

But I would recommand also to use explicit/implicit waits instread of Thread.sleep (I've linked an [article](https://dzone.com/articles/waits-in-selenium-how-to-use-implicit-amp-explicit), you can find more information on google).